# how to uninstall pyenv(installed by homebrew) on Mac

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

I used to install pyenv by homebrew to manage versions of python, but now, I want to use anaconda.But I don't know how to uninstall pyenv.Please tell me.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[From the docs:](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#uninstalling-pyenv)

> #### Uninstalling pyenv
>
> The simplicity of pyenv makes it easy to temporarily disable it, or
> uninstall from the system.
>
> 1. To **disable** Pyenv managing your Python versions, simply remove the `pyenv init` line from your shell startup configuration. This will remove Pyenv shims directory from PATH, and future invocations like `python` will execute the system Python version, as before Pyenv.
>
>    `pyenv` will still be accessible on the command line, but your
>    Python   apps won't be affected by version switching.
> 2. To completely **uninstall** pyenv, perform step (1) and then remove its root directory. This will **delete all Python versions** that were installed under `$(pyenv root)/versions/` directory:
>
>    ```sh
>    rm -rf $(pyenv root)
>    ```
>
>    If you've installed Pyenv using a package manager, as a final step perform the Pyenv package removal. For instance, for Homebrew:
>
>    ```
>     brew uninstall pyenv
>    ```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the relevant lines from your shell environment config

Comment: 1. says, "perform step (1) and then remove its root directory." What is step (1)?

Comment: @brec [From the docs:](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md#uninstalling-pyenv) “remove the `pyenv init` line from your shell startup configuration.” Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing it using the following command:

`brew remove pyenv`

Comment: Thanks very much for your  quick answer!

Answer (score 4):

None work for me (under brew) under Mac Cataline.

They have a warning about file missing under `.pyenv`.

(After I removed the `bash_profile` lines and also `rm -rf ~/.pyenv`,

I just install Mac OS version of python under `python.org` and seems ok.

Seems get my IDLE work and ...