# ssl module in Python is not available on macos

Tags: python, pip, openssl, homebrew

So it may sound like duplicate of multiple other pots ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280484/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-on-osx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)) but none of these pots were able to solve my problem.

I am trying to run `pip3 install pipenv` command and getting following error

```
$ pip3 install pipenv
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pipenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pipenv/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pipenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pipenv/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I have already tried `brew uninstall openssl` and then `brew install openssl` (i had to do uninstall with `--ignore-dependency` flag since i have `awscli` installed which is using it). I also have following variables set in my `~/.zshrc`

```
 $ tail -4 ~/.zshrc
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export CPPFLAGS=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
export LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

So i am not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

For me, switching to an older version of `openssl` worked:

`brew switch openssl 1.0.2t`

I'm on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3. Hope it helps.