# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ssl, pip, macos-catalina

I have tried all the answers for this problem but so far none of them worked.
Whenever I use pip I get :

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.0.2)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
```

I installed the new Catalina OS (10.15.3) some days ago.
If I do:

```
(tensorflow) MBP-de-Hector-2:~ hectoresteban$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/hectoresteban/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hectoresteban/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL module in Python is not available (on OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280484/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-on-osx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+pip+is+configured+with+locations+that+require+TLS%2FSSL%2C+however+the+ssl+module+in+Python+is+not+available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)