# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. Python 3.6.5 in Catalina MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using MacOS Catalina and I have downgraded my python version from 3.7.7 to 3.6.5 to work on my old Django project. When I use pip3 install or python3 -m pip install, i am getting following error - pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. This might be similar to existing questions but I tried most of the response it didn't fix it. Mostly I think, it is due to Catalina and python 3.6.5

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer in this link:
[pip is configured..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: I did tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at [SSL module in Python is not available (on OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280484/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-on-osx)